# How to test performance of a Google sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-performance

I was wondering, whether `ARRAY_FORMULA()` enclosed by `COUNT()` work much slower than `COUNTIF()` without `ARRAY_FORMULA()`. How to test/compare performance of formula that uses a range as parameter?

Comment: It's really great that you are using this site to share your findings about using Google Sheets and that you are posting a self answered question. Please bear in mind that questions on this Stack Exchange sites  should be worded as questions. There are guidelines about this on Meta ( not sure if there is one in [meta] but certainly there are on [meta.se]

Comment: @Rubén thank you. I edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: I removed the "noise" as it's implicit that posters are open for comments and suggestions (those that aren't should not post here), also removed the comment that you are sharing the solution as it's obvious as it was posted at the same time than the question. It could be nice if self-answerers write their questions imaging themselves as a user that doesn't know the answer and is making their best effort to write a good question, meaning, describing the problem and an imaginary results of their search/research efforts prior founding the solution, but that could be too much...

Comment: ... so just giving a brief context of why this is a real/practical problem will be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I created [this test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APM2kIwv6-MokEDE7O_GCMwqJiQHLAhQxVYCmfTl_Io/edit?usp=sharing) the following way. I created a new spreadsheet, then deleted all columns but one, and then added as much rows as Google allowed me (between 4 and 5 million rows). 
Then I added the following formulas:

```
1 | =SECOND(NOW()) & " | " & COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A$8:A, 1, 1))) & " | " & SECOND(NOW())
2 | =INDEX(SPLIT(A$1," |"),3)
3 | =INDEX(SPLIT(A$1," |"),1)
4 | ="Total execution time in seconds: " & IF(A3-A2 >= 0, A3-A2, A3 + 60 - A2)
```

Now I caused recalculation of the formulas, by entering `0` in cell `A8`. I entered and removed "0" in that cell several times to see that if the results were the same or different. After each changing of `A8` I had to wait for formulas to recalculate. Every time the formulas were recalculated, it recorded the total time of calculation in `A4`. I replaced `COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A$8:A, 1, 1)))` with other formulas to compare performance of different formulas.

It is interesting the second `NOW()` is calculated before the `COUNT()` and the first `NOW()` is calculated after the `COUNT()`. I discovered this by manually checking the time, when re-calculation started and finished with the windows clock and comparing it with the results in `A1`, `A2` and `A3`

This is some test results I obtained. I executed the test 8 times for each of the two formulas and calculated average result.

```
Formula                | Execution time, seconds, attempts 
                       |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  AVERAGE
-----------------------|-----------------------------------
COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(    |
    IF(A$8:A, 1, 1)))  | 18 18 17 17 17 16 18 19  17.50 sec
                       |
COUNTIF(A$8:A, "")     | 18 18 18 20 18 18 18 18  18.25 sec
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how this exactly can possibly act as an answer to the question... whats the final verdict of your findings? whats faster? (also I have a huge hunch that this method is not enough transparent and the calculation was compromised on few different levels like usage of NOW, coping multiple formulas in calculation run, etc.)

Comment: @user0 totally agree

Comment: the answer updated

Comment: how usage of NOW()  compromises the test? It is easy to check that if the tested expression is removed from the formula in cell A1, both NOWs return the same result, so they do not influence the test

Comment: Checkout this [Measurement of execution time of built-in functions for Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923770/1595451)

Comment: @user0 While the current revision doesn't look as the "ultimate answer", it's a lot better than the first one, Don't you think? By the other hand while using the "windows clock" could be "convenient", it could be more precise to use the web browser developer tools.